# OpenID Connect and Azure AD Users and Groups

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to configure a OpenID Connect with Azure AD. I can do it creating a App in **App Registration Menu** and everything works fine. See image:

[image]

But with **App Registration Menu** i don't have the "Users and Groups" menu  (like **Enterprise Applications**) where i can give permissions saying which users can LOGIN in my application.

So, trying to create a **Enterprise Application** using the option **Non-Gallery Application** but i have just **SAML** option as Federated Single Sign-On, i don't have OPENID CONNECT option.

[image]

Any ideia how to create OpenID Connect as Federated Single Sign-On ? Or give Users and Groups permissions to a normal App Registration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enterprise Applications are linked to registered applications. What you need to do is create the Registered Application, this will create you an Enterprise Application with the same name. You can then add the users and groups on the Enterprise Application and through the link created when you act as the application allows the users and groups to be gotten through this.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks, now everything works as expected. you saved my day

Comment: Glad you're sorted! It's worth observing that the application id for the App Registration and the Enterprise Application is the same.

Comment: Enterprise applications are actually service principals under the hood, if you are looking for them from Graph API. An app registration is an Application on the Graph. Users can only be given roles and access on service principals, and when you create an App registration, it creates the Service principal at the same time.

Comment: And similarly when you give an app some permissions, they are actually granted on the service principal, not the application.

Comment: Absolutely right, which is why in multi tenanted applications if you apply a permission to the application in the source tenant you have to grant the permission on the service principals in all the tenants utilising the application